How to resolve "this dApp could be malicious" warning in Phantom?
Phantom shows the following warning:

This dApp could be malicious. Do not proceed unless you are certain this is safe. If you think this is incorrect, reach out at review@blowfish.xyz

I sent an email to the official team, but I haven't received a resolution even after a week.

Your message (in the screenshot, but now converted to text) said to contact review@blowfish.xyz. You said you contacted 'the official team' in the question - was this review@blowfish.xyz or some other email address?

Phantom and Backpack use Blowfish to identify and warn users of potential phishing sites.
If, you are an app developer, you need to reach out to blowfish and have them whitelist your app if flagged.
review@blowfish.xyz
